# Vue Axios Push Array isn't updated live

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, jspdf-autotable

I have a problem, when I'm using jspdf autotable to generate table pdf
and I am using axios to get dynamic lists, the problem is when I click button preview once there is no result

Once Click Preview Button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUisd.png)

but when I click preview once more there is a result

Once More Click Preview Button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFXXk.png)

And here is my code

HTML

```
<template>
    <div id="report" class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <v-flex xs12>
                        <v-radio-group v-model="document_category" row>
                        <v-radio label="Draft" value="DRAFT"></v-radio>
                        <v-radio label="Original" value="ORIGINAL"></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs12>
                            <v-text-field v-model="profile_id" prepend-icon="text_fields" placeholder="Enter Title" label="Title" @keyup.enter="Report('preview')"></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>
                        <v-flex xs12>
                        <v-text-field v-model="profile_name" prepend-icon="sort" placeholder="Enter Content" label="Content" @keyup.enter="Report('preview')"></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>
                    </div>
                    <v-btn color="success" flat @click="Report('preview')">Preview</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="error" flat @click="Report('newwindow')">Preview On New Window</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="primary" flat @click="Report('print')">Preview and Print</v-btn><br><br>
                    <app-dialogloading :visible="dialog_loading" />
                    <iframe width="100%" height="500px" :src="urlpdf" v-if="urlpdf"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog_preview_print" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
        <v-card>
            <v-toolbar flat dark color="primary">
                <v-btn icon dark @click.stop="dialog_preview_print = false">
                <v-icon>arrow_back</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-toolbar-title>Preview</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            </v-toolbar>
                <iframe width="100%" height="600px" :src="urlpdf" v-if="urlpdf"></iframe>
        </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
require('jspdf-autotable')
export default {
    name: 'PN001',
    props: {
        referenceno: String
    },
    data: () => ({
        document_category: 'DRAFT',
        profile_id: '',
        profile_name: '',
        urlpdf: '',
        dialog_loading: false,
        dialog_preview_print: false,
        rows: []
    }),
    created() {
        this.profile_id = this.$props.referenceno
        if (this.$route.query.download === 'Y') {
            this.Report('download')
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Report (flag) {
            if (flag !== '') {
                let pdfName = 'riva'
                let doc = new jsPDF()
                doc.setFontType('bold')
                doc.setFontSize(12)
                let pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height || doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight()
                let pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width || doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()
                doc.setFillColor(255,255,255)
                doc.rect(172,4,30,8,'FD')
                doc.text(this.document_category,180,10)
                doc.text(this.profile_id, pageWidth / 2, pageHeight  - 285, 'center')
                doc.setFontType('')
                doc.setFontSize(10)
                doc.text(this.profile_name, 10,20, {maxWidth: 190, align: 'justify'})
                let columns = [
                    {title: 'ID', dataKey: 'profile_id'},
                    {title: 'Name', dataKey: 'profile_name'},
                    {title: 'Actived', dataKey: 'profile_actived'}
                ]
                this.TableList()
                doc.autoTable(columns, this.rows)
            if (flag === 'download') {
                doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf')
            } else if (flag === 'preview') {
                this.dialog_loading = true
                this.urlpdf = doc.output('bloburl')+'#toolbar=0'
                this.dialog_loading = false
            }  else if (flag === 'newwindow') {
                this.dialog_loading = true
                this.dialog_preview_print = true
                this.urlpdf = doc.output('bloburl')+'#toolbar=0'
                this.dialog_loading = false
            } else if (flag === 'print') {
                this.dialog_loading = true
                doc.autoPrint()
                this.urlpdf = doc.output('bloburl')
                this.dialog_loading = false
            } 
        }
        },
        TableList (){
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('profile_id', this.profile_id)
            formData.append('profile_name', this.profile_name)
            this.$axios.post(this.$functions.SafeURL('apiListProfile', ``), formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
            this.rows = []
            for (let i = 0;i < response.data.length;i++) {
                this.rows.push({profile_id: response.data[i].profile_id,profile_name: response.data[i].profile_name,profile_actived: response.data[i].profile_actived})
            }
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once click https://forum.vuejs.org/uploads/default/original/3X/b/f/bf29a0b2910624b383296857787b92e151a42714.png

Once More Click
https://forum.vuejs.org/uploads/default/original/3X/4/a/4ac305fd17485523fe5745d74786dbadcacf3101.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes to `rows` are detected by Vue, if you add `{{ rows }}` in the template you'd see that.

But changes made the rows don't automatically result in change of the `urlpdf` value.

You can add a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `rows` to run the code that updates pdfurl, but in this case I would just call the `Report()` method after the response is processed and the rows contain the results, like so:

```
.then(response => {
  this.rows = []
  for (let i = 0;i < response.data.length;i++) {
    this.rows.push({profile_id: response.data[i].profile_id,profile_name: response.data[i].profile_name,profile_actived: response.data[i].profile_actived})
  }
  this.Report('preview') // <- here
})
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, apologize but Im still not get it, would you please to provide sample?